# What is the purpose of the plush-like seat covers in an airliner cockpit?

Tags: airliner, cockpit, seats

What is the purpose of the plush-like seat covers that I have seen on almost all the airliners I looked at? See for example the following picture of a Bombardier CRJ flight deck:

[image]
([wikimedia.org](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bombardier_CL-600-2E25_Regional_Jet_CRJ-1000_NextGen,_Brit_Air_AN1967464.jpg))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Check out this related question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/5152/why-do-pilots-seat-covers-almost-uniformly-use-sheepskin)

[And this forum topic.](http://www.airliners.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=52537)

They help prevent wear and tear on the seat fabric underneath and are fairly easy to replace. In a lot of GA planes they are installed to hide old tired seats underneath. But mostly they are just [really really comfortable](https://www.aircraftspruce.com/categories/aircraft_parts/ap/menus/ap/seat_sheepskin.html). They breathe in warm weather and help insulate in cold. All around a good fabric choice for the application (see related question for notes on fire prevention).

Comment: It's not just the airlines.  I have them in my Cessna Cardinal, similar to these https://www.shearcomfort.com/Airplane-Seat-Covers.asp?utm_source=google_shopping&utm_medium=cpc&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI3s2Hpfqt3AIVUC-BCh0dxQD3EAQYASABEgKKOPD_BwE  Mine are 20 years old, I've long ago forgotten what brand, but cool in summer and warm in winter. I haven't flown in a few years, I'd forgotten how comfortable they are now that I am flying again.