# Did the SR-71 have any windshields?

Tags: aircraft-design, cockpit, windows, sr-71

In this video of a more [complex](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2873/why-are-the-cockpit-controls-of-airplanes-so-complicated) cockpit, belonging to the SR-71, why don't we see any windshields? Were they not required for the SR-71, or are they not captured in this video? If windshields were actually not there, then please elaborate why!

[image]

[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tj9UwKQKE3A)

Comment: That's just a picture of the instrument panel, the SR-71 did have windows.

Comment: foolish question then... !!

Comment: Just seek the video to ~8:40 where the camera pans up over the windows and to the mirrors and periscope above them.

Comment: On the other hand note that the navigator station (behind pilot), also shown later in that video, did indeed not have forward view, only two side windows to provide some natural light. Unlike most 2-crew fighters it didn't have flight controls either.

Comment: The windshields would be getting so hot that the crew would actually heat up their rations by pressing them against the windshield, so, yes, the Blackbird *did* have windshields, and they were in some sense even vital to mission success :-D

Comment: I'm sorry but this is a completely ridiculous question. Just look at *any* exterior photograph of an SR-71 cockpit and you can see the windows as clear as day. Or, as @JanHudec points out, the windows are visible in the very video you're asking about.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is completely ridiculous. The answer is 100% obvious from looking at any exterior photograph of the plane.

Comment: @DavidRicherby yes this is, I am voting to close it as well! But, this bought a huge bunch of rep to the answerers  anyways...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are forward-facing windows in the SR-71. The image you posted is just of the instrument panel. The windows are better visible in the photo below. This is from a simulator but gives a better idea of what the cockpit looks like when in flight.

The windows and cockpit are small due to the high speeds and altitudes that the plane is designed for, making the cockpit resemble a smaller fighter plane.

[image: SR-71 Cockpit]

As a side note, there are planes without windshields, a notable example being the [Spirit of St. Louis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirit_of_St._Louis).

Answer (score 24):

It did!
You can see a bit of it here

[image]

or in the reflection here 
[image]

And here it is from the exterior
[image]